# Python create a list from the last column of each row in a csv

Tags: python, list, csv, python-3.x

I'm using python 3.3. I have a csv file but I just want the last column of each row to be used as a list. I'm able to display this but I can't just store it as a list. 
Here's the code I used.

```
my_list = []
with open(home + filePath , newline='') as f:
     Array = (line.split(',') for line in f.readlines())
     for row in Array:
          #this prints out the whole csv file
          #this prints out just the last row but I can't use it as a list
          print(', '.join(row))
          print(row[6])

   print(my_list)
```

So how would I go about taking the last column of each row (row[6]) and putting that into a list that I could use as integers?

Answer (score 4):

Use the `csv` module for ease of use, then a list comprehension:

```
import csv
import os

with open(os.path.join(home, filePath), newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    my_list = [row[-1] for row in reader]
```

Note that I use `row[-1]` to pick out the last element of each row.

Your code never added anything to `my_list`; a `my_list.append(row[6])` would have fixed that.